# MongoDB Update document and change position in collection

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, react-beautiful-dnd

I have a react-beautiful-dnd Kanban with tasks. The tasks are rendered by the stored order in MongoDB.

On the Kanban, when I change the position of a task from 3 to 55, I want to update the task in MongoDB and move it from position 3 to 55 in the collection.

Is that possible?

If not, any ideas on how to solve that problem?

*Update: Collection currently looks like this:*

```
    _id: ObjectId("6284ad4053fc5bd9f17908e0")
    columnId: "625ebad450ff6f16df133053"
    stepId: "6257b090c9677c26b4c9c274"
    title: "Task 1"
    priority: "Low"

    _id: ObjectId("6284aab153fc5bd9f1790892")
    columnId: "625ebad450ff6f16df133054"
    stepId: "6257b090c9677c26b4c9c275"
    title: "Task 2"
    priority:"Medium"
    
    ...
```

Comment: can you provide your document and collection structure?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: A mognodb collection is not aware of any order of your documents. You have to add a custom field to your model and update it.

Comment: @mcanzerini Let's say I have 100000 documents. If I add an index field and move a task from 3 to 999, I would have to reindex lots of other entries. Task with index 999 is going to have index 998, task 998 index 997, task 997 index 996...

Comment: @Tonimarroni you don't always need to keep the numbering. You can simply update task 3 to task 999.5(or just some number between 999 and 1000). The idea is to design a sort key field to help you perform the `$sort` operation. But the actual manifestation requires more context from your actual scenario.